# Uninstall nginx installed by Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, package, passenger, uninstallation

How do I uninstall nginx installed as part of passenger installation on Ubuntu 11.04?

Should I just `gem uninstall passenger`? Will that remove nginx as well?

This is what I see when I run `apt-get remove`:

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx-common nginx-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
**Package nginx-common is not installed, so not removed
Package nginx-full is not installed, so not removed**
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  nspluginwrapper linux-headers-2.6.38-13-generic libmysqlclient-dev libaprutil1-ldap libaprutil1-dev libmysqlclient16 libdb4.8-dev libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
  apache2.2-bin linux-headers-2.6.38-14-generic linux-headers-2.6.38-12 linux-headers-2.6.38-13 linux-headers-2.6.38-14 mysql-common linux-headers-2.6.38-12-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
```

Comment: According to this error message, you don't have nginx installed -- at least through aptitude. What makes you think that you do?

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge nginx-*`, `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: i am not sure what the mechanism that passenger uses to compile and install nginx but it does exist. i could see it running when i look at services nginx status or /etc/init.d/nginx status

Answer (score 3):

You most likely used `passenger-install-nginx-module` to install it. If you run `gem uninstall passenger` it will remove the dependent modules as well.

Comment: This does not appear to be the case: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#uninstalling

Answer (score 2):

Uninstallation is covered in the official manual "[Phusion Passenger users guide, Nginx version](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#uninstalling)".

Comment: This doesn't cover uninstalling the nginx that might've been downloaded with `passenger-install-nginx-module`

Comment: This *does* discuss it though. "Nginx does not have to be recompiled after uninstalling Phusion Passenger. Altough Nginx will contain the Phusion Passenger Nginx module, the module will not do anything when all Phusion Passenger configuration directives are removed."

Answer (score 2):

Use following commands to completely remove Nginx:

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx-*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

OR

**For Debian/Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get remove -y passenger
```

**Red Hat/CentOS**

```
sudo yum remove -y passenger
```

**macOS + Homebrew**

```
brew uninstall passenger
```

**Ruby gem**

```
gem uninstall passenger
```

Hope this will solve your problem!

Comment: you made my day!